# Low display resolution on primary display and secondary display not recognised

Tags: display, display-resolution, monitor

Basically, I have 2 monitors.

A `1680 x 1050` one (my main) and a Sony `1080 x 1024` one, my secondary.

After getting all my drivers installed, I find that my resolution on my main monitor is locked to `800 x 600` and is just defined as "Unknown Display"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if there is anything I need to attach just let me know

Comment: still need help wit hthis